# Programmatically create media file

Tags: 8, media

I'm trying to programmatically create a media file. Here's what I got so far:

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf');

$file = file_save_data($file_data, 'public://3010.pdf', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

$media = Media::create([
  'bundle' => 'file',
  'uid' => '0',
  'field_media_file' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
  ],
]);

$media->setName('Hello')
  ->setPublished(TRUE)
  ->save();
```

Unfortunately this returns me the following error and the media file doesn't get saved:

> Error: Call to a member function getSource() on null in Drupal\media\Entity\Media->getSource() (line 138 of core/modules/media/src/Entity/Media.php).

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 10):

`uid` shouldn't be 0, just change `'uid' => '0'` by `'uid'=> \Drupal::currentUser()->id()`:

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf');
$file = file_save_data($file_data, 'public://3010.pdf', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
$media = Media::create([
  'bundle'           => 'file',
  'uid'              => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
  'field_media_file' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
  ],
]);
$media->setName('Hello')->setPublished(TRUE)->save();
```

Answer (score 6):

Things have changed a bit since the advent of Drupal 9 and the Media module in core. Notice that the bundle is now `'document'`.  You can find the media types at /admin/structure/media: Hover your mouse over the edit button and you'll see the media type in the URL.

```php
$file_data = file_get_contents('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf');
$file = file_save_data($file_data, 'public://3010.pdf', FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);
$media = Media::create([
  'bundle'=> 'document',
  'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
  'field_media_document' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
  ],
]);

$media->setName('3010 Sample PDF')
  ->setPublished(TRUE)
  ->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
Use `\Drupal::service('file.repository')->writeData()` instead of `file_save_data` in Drupal 10

I got `Call to undefined function Drupal\custom_module\Commands\file_save_data()`

Here's the change record:
https://www.drupal.org/node/3223520