# How can I migrate an Amazon S3 bucket to into Drupal?

Tags: files, migrations, 8

**SCENARIO**

I currently have a bucket where all my images are hosted and stored. I currently display them by simply using URLs that link to the images (i.e https://[bucketName].s3.amazonaws.com/[imageName]).

I currently have over 22k photos in the bucket but I want migrate them over to the Drupal database.

**PROBLEM**

This was how I planned on resolving this:

1. I was thinking of trying to find an API that would get a list of all the objects in my bucket.
2. Then after getting the list off all the objects, use PHP's `file_get_contents()` function to get the image itself
3. Then programmatically create the Media type after each URL request, by following what I saw here, [Programmatically create media file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282384/programmatically-create-media-file) or possibly doing this [Create file/media](https://gist.github.com/steffenr/a40bab1f3b1c066d5c0655351e2107fd)

**QUESTION**

Is this a proper approach? Or is there a better way for me to approach this?

Comment: Might be possible with the Migrate API.

Comment: I'd also suggest Migrate API. also check the contrib modules Migrate Plus and Migrate Tools, they might completely save you from custom coding.

Comment: Check this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/remote-stream-wrapper